# Is it possible to create a simple smart pointer baseclass without templates?

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, smart-pointers, reference-counting

I was wondering if it is possible to create a smart pointer baseclass without using a template?

I have seen a number of implementations but all use tempalates. 
For example, implementing the smart pointer logics in a base class which other classes derive from.

Comment: Can you give some sort of example of what you want? Do you want some sort of 'typeless' `shared_ptr` with which you wouldn't be able to access the contained data, but which you could hold on to for a long time in order to delay destruction?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid templates? Describing your goals (a smart pointer which works in situation X), rather than a specific attempt at a solution (avoid templates) might make it possible to provide a better solution

Comment: You could write a non-template base class that uses `void*` for the pointer being managed, then a template class that derives from that base class and adds the type safety. Users only see the class template. Is that what you're talking about? I suspect it's fairly pointless, though, in that whatever code you'd put in the base class could just as well be in a helper class that isn't a base class, so it's a fairly unimportant implementation detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the class of your pointer member.

In languages like C# it is possible, because there is an **"object"** class, from which every other class derives. You would lose type safety in that case.

However, in C++ you don't have such a thing, which leaves you with 2 choices:

1. Using **void***  and **reinterpet_cast** - very ugly, really not safe due to type safety.
2. Writing tons of overloads for your class - for each and every class. Not feasible, because it will not work with new classes.

Thus, the best way is to use templates.
By the way, the idea of *template* is so good that C# started to use it after some version.

Comment: Isn't it enough to write overloads for the baseclass?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan, baseclass of what?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your smart pointer class to act as a resource managing class for only a particular data type of resource then you dont need a template.

If you are planning to write a generic resource manager class then you do need a template class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using this approach is that you can't add methods. Yes, you can use inheritance for creating smart pointers if you want but the result would be rather limited. In this case, inheritance is **not** the best solution. Dynamic polymorphism is rarely the best solution but this is a different and much bigger discussion (note that I haven't said it *never* is).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why

```
#include <iostream>

class void_scoped_ptr {
public:
  virtual ~void_scoped_ptr() = 0;
  void operator=(void_scoped_ptr const&) = delete;

  explicit operator bool() const { return ptr != 0; }

protected:
  void_scoped_ptr(void* p) : ptr(p) {};

  void* ptr;
};

void_scoped_ptr::~void_scoped_ptr() {}

#define MAKE_DERIVED_SCOPED_BASE(T, NAME, DELETE, DEREF)                    \
class NAME : void_scoped_ptr {                                              \
public:                                                                     \
  typedef T element_type;                                                   \
  typedef element_type* ptr_type;                                           \
  typedef element_type const* const_ptr_type;                               \
                                                                            \
  NAME(ptr_type p) : void_scoped_ptr(p) {}                                  \
  ~ NAME() { DELETE cast(); }                                               \
  void reset(ptr_type p) {                                                  \
    DELETE cast();                                                          \
    ptr = p;                                                                \
  }                                                                         \
                                                                            \
  DEREF                                                                     \
  element_type& operator*() { return *cast(); }                             \
  element_type const& operator*() const { return *cast(); }                 \
                                                                            \
protected:                                                                  \
  ptr_type cast() { return static_cast<ptr_type>(ptr); }                    \
  const_ptr_type cast() const { return static_cast<ptr_type>(ptr); }        \
}

#define MAKE_DERIVED_SCOPED_PTR(T)                                          \
  MAKE_DERIVED_SCOPED_BASE(T, T ## _scoped_ptr, delete,                     \
    ptr_type operator->() { return cast(); }                                \
    const_ptr_type operator->() const { return cast(); }                    \
  )
#define MAKE_DERIVED_SCOPED_ARRAY(T)                                        \
  MAKE_DERIVED_SCOPED_BASE(T, T ## _scoped_array, delete [],                \
    element_type& operator[](size_t i) { return cast()[i]; }                \
    element_type const& operator[](size_t i) const { return cast()[i]; }    \
  )

struct TestClass {
  TestClass() { std::cout << "construct\n"; }
  ~TestClass() { std::cout << "destruct\n"; }

  void f() { std::cout << "f()\n"; }
};

typedef MAKE_DERIVED_SCOPED_PTR(TestClass) test_ptr;
typedef MAKE_DERIVED_SCOPED_ARRAY(TestClass) test_array;

int main() {
  {
    test_ptr p(new TestClass);
    p->f();
  }

  {
    test_array a(new TestClass[3]);
    a[2].f();
  }
}
```